# App Fails to Render Data Fetched from API on Firebase Test Lab and Android Console

Tags: android, react-native

I'm facing an issue where my app does not render data fetched from an API when run on Firebase Test Lab and the Android console, although it works fine in the local environment debug mode. Here's a detailed description of the problem:

Local Environment (Debug Mode): The app functions correctly and renders the fetched data as expected.
[image: Data fetched correct on debug mode]

Firebase Test Lab & Android Console: The app looks visually identical to the debug mode but fails to render any fetched data.

[image: Data not fetched on apk file]

What I've tried so far:

- Ensured that network permissions are correctly set in the Android Manifest file.

```
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

- I have also set internet permissions as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

I am fetching data from "http://[aws zone ].elasticbeanstalk.com"

My question:

- What could be causing this discrepancy in data rendering between the local debug environment and Firebase Test Lab/Android Console?
- Are there specific settings or permissions I need to adjust for Firebase Test Lab or the Android console?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to Resolve this by adding the following lines to the Manifest files
First I added this to the manifest opening tag

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
```

And then I added this to the application tag

```
<application
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"
      >
```